# show element on top of a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this html5 dialog

```
<dialog>
    <h1>hello</h1>
</dialog>
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

At some point I show it like

```
$('dialog')[0].showModal();
```

Now, the dialog is on top of all elements in the page (ignoring z-index) which is what I want (nothing in the page should be clickable for example)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zk0qgh93/)

However, I have this spinner in my site which gets visible when an API call takes longer than 500ms. The problem is that the spinner is behind the dialog now. Is it possible to have the spinner on top of the modal dialog ?

Comment: Have you tried to give a z-index to the spinner? It should be higher than the z-index of the dialog though.

Comment: Give it a high z-index and use show() instead of showModal(). showModal() by design prevents any other element from being interactive http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_dialog_showmodal.asp

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<h1>afefeg</h1>
<dialog>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <div class="spinner" style="display:block"></div>
</dialog>
```

Now hide and show the spinner.

EDIT CODE :

Try this one.

HTML

```
 <h1>afefeg</h1>
<dialog class="overlay">
    <h1>hello</h1>

</dialog>

<dialog  class="dailog-spinner" style="width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;display:none">
 <div > HI </div>
</dialog>
```

JS :

```
$(function () {
    $('dialog')[0].show();
     $('.dailog-spinner')[0].showModal();

});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zk0qgh93/33/)

Comment: I think he would like the spinner to be always on top.

Comment: yep, thats true @AndréPacheco, I have this spinner in my `body` and now I would like it to work in case of this dialog too

Comment: interesting approach!!